# Pairwise independent normal random variables implies they are all independent..

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_1,\dotsc,X_n:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are pairwise independent random variables with $X_i$ having normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. How can we see that these are all independent.

This question has been asked before, see for instance:
[Pairwise independence implies independence for normal random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1750236/pairwise-independence-implies-independence-for-normal-random-variables)

However I trouble understanding the answer. I don't see how one can get the density of the joint distribution.

Comment: If the vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is Gaussian then this follows from no pairwise correlation. If it is not Gaussian then I'm not sure (I would expect there to be a counterexample).

Comment: So Gaussian here means that we can find a Gaussian vector $Y = (Y_1,\dotsc,Y_n)$ where $Y_1,\dotsc,Y_n$ are independent, a matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ such that $X = AY+b$?

Comment: Where $Y$ is Gaussian with diagonal covariance matrix, yes. The general definition is: any linear combination of the $X_i$s is normally distributed.

Comment: Ok so in the question I linked to, the key is that $X$ is a Gaussian vector